# Local function definitions are rejected by Visual Studio

Tags: c, tags, device

I am trying to list all devices attached to my system and after searching found this code which throws up error local function definations are illegal can someone explain what its means please.

Or is my issue because I am trying to use code that was from in C++. Thanks

WORKING CODE

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"SetupAPI") 


void print_property
(
    __in HDEVINFO hDevInfo,
    __in SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData,
    __in PCWSTR Label,
    __in DWORD Property
)
{
    DWORD DataT;
    LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
    DWORD buffersize = 0;

    // 
    while (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
                hDevInfo,
                &DeviceInfoData,
                Property,
                &DataT,
                (PBYTE)buffer,
                buffersize,
                &buffersize))
    {
        if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
        {
            // Change the buffer size.
            if (buffer)
            {
                LocalFree(buffer);
            }
            // Double the size to avoid problems on 
            // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609. 
            buffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, buffersize * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    wprintf(L"%s %s\n",Label, buffer);

    if (buffer)
    {
        LocalFree(buffer);
    }
}



int main() 
{


    //int setupdi_version()
    //{
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    DWORD i;

    // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
        NULL,
        0, // Enumerator
        0,
        DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hDevInfo)
    {
        // Insert error handling here.
        return 1;
    }

    // Enumerate through all devices in Set.

    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

    for (i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, &DeviceInfoData); i++)
    {
        LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
        DWORD buffersize = 0;

        print_property(hDevInfo, DeviceInfoData, L"Friendly name :", SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME);

        while (!SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(
            hDevInfo, 
            &DeviceInfoData, 
            buffer, 
            buffersize, 
            &buffersize))
        {
            if (buffer)
            {
                LocalFree(buffer);
            }

            if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
            {
                // Change the buffer size.
                // Double the size to avoid problems on
                // W2k MBCS systems per KB 888609.
                buffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, buffersize * 2);
            }
            else
            {
                wprintf(L"error: could not get device instance id (0x%x)\n", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
        }

        if (buffer)
        {
            wprintf(L"\tDeviceInstanceId : %s\n", buffer);
        }

        print_property(hDevInfo, DeviceInfoData, L"\tClass :", SPDRP_CLASS);
        print_property(hDevInfo, DeviceInfoData, L"\tClass GUID :", SPDRP_CLASSGUID);
    }


    if (NO_ERROR != GetLastError() && ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS != GetLastError())
    {
        // Insert error handling here.
        return 1;
    }

    // Cleanup
    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);

    system ("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you fix your code formatting it's easier to see that you have unbalanced curly braces and a typo somewhere. It looks like it starts to go wrong around the `int setupdi_version()` line.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation, but as @Blastfurnace says there are still problems. The definition of `setupdi_version()` appears to begin inside the definition of `main()` -- but there are no calls to `setupdi_version()`, and there's a missing closing brace. Can you tell us where you found this code? And the `#include <string>` implies that this is C++ code.

Comment: Indentation is really important. I edited your post to correct the indentation, then your edit left-justified everything again. ... I've just fixed the indentation again.

Comment: What's the point of deleting the code?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will compile and run if you comment out the following two lines as shown:

```
// int setupdi_version()
// {
```

I think the original code is from a function named `setupdi_version()` and it got mangled a bit when you tried to change it to `main()`. Note: it looks like the original source code is from [here](http://samscode.blogspot.com/2009/08/setupdi-how-to-enumerate-devices-using.html).

To answer your follow-on problem. Those are linker errors. You need to tell Visual Studio which `.lib` file(s) to link against. You can do that in the Visual Studio project dependencies or just add the following to the top of the source code.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"SetupAPI")
```

Comment: thanks that was the site good detective work :-) however i now get unresolved externals when I ghost that part out.

For example Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4 referenced in function _main c:\Users\K\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SetupDI\SetupDI\main.obj SetupDI

Comment: @CorrieDuck: I added a fix for the linker problem.

Comment: Thank you so much much it now works really appreciate your help this has been sending me mad for days trying to get this info.

Answer (score 1):

You have another function defined inside the body of `main`; this is invalid C. Move it outside of `main`.

Comment: Some compilers may allow this as an extension (I believe gcc does, for example), but it's non-standard in both C and C++.

Comment: Thanks for the replys I tried to move the int setupdi_version() part outside of main throws up about 29 errors. Is there a good way to format this or should I bin this and look elsewhere?

Comment: "If you're going to break the line in the middle of a function call, indent the second line one past the opening paren *of the function call*" would be a good start.  I've seen a lot of wacky indentation in my time, but indenting arguments only as far as the outer `while` or `if` statement...!

Comment: Thanks I found it on a blog it was from c++ but I was trying to convert it to c as I made an application which reads phone by usb but the device paths change slightly so I was trying get the pull path vid+pid+guid. I was looking for a working example of SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId and SetupDiGetClassDevs in C. I read up on MSDN but a bit confusing and only c++ examples.

Comment: @CorrieDuck: The compiler doesn't care how the code is formatted (though anyone reading it does).